# Pig get distinct rows with counts

Tags: count, apache-pig, distinct, uniq

I have a pig table (called table1) containing many duplicates and more than one column (called col1, col2)

Here is a simple example

```
| col1 | col2 |
-----------------
|  111 | bbb |
|  111 | ccc |
|  111 | bbb |
|  222 | bbb |
```

I would like to get the distinct lines with the count of their appearance (like using uniq -c in bash), so that the result would be :

```
| count |col1 | col2 |
-----------------
|  2 | 111 | bbb |
|  1 | 111 | ccc |
|  1 | 222 | bbb |
```

What is the syntax for such a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
A = LOAD 'data'....;
GR = GROUP A by (col1,col2);
CNT = FOREACH GR GENERATE FLATTEN (group) AS (col1,col2) , COUNT(A) as cnt_col;
dump CNT;
```